# How to compare MySQL binary UUID using dynamic SQL in Mybatis

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

We store one of the UUID values as `binary(16)` in mysql db.

spec

```
 MyTable myTable = new MyTable();` //table
 SqlColumn<Long> id = column("id");` // id column
 SqlColumn<UUID> myUuidColumn = column("my_uuid");` //uuid column
```

Dynamic sql query for select.

```
            select(myTable.id)
                .from(myTable)
                .where(myTable.myUuidColumn, isEqualTo(UUID.fromString("e59bf2fd-e742-4314-ab02-db195e0168c8")))
                .build()
                .render(RenderingStrategies.MYBATIS3);
```

But this is not working, probably due to UUID is not being natively supported. How to fix this other than changing the mapper to use plain sql query?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a custom type handler.
The implementation depends on the driver and/or the column type.
Here is the type handler implementation for your usage (i.e. `BINARY(16)`).

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;

@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.BINARY)
public class UuidTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<UUID> {
  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, UUID parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    ps.setBytes(i, uuidToBytes(parameter));
  }

  private static byte[] uuidToBytes(UUID uuid) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
    bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    return bb.array();
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    return bytesToUuid(rs.getBytes(columnName));
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return bytesToUuid(rs.getBytes(columnIndex));
  }

  @Override
  public UUID getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    return bytesToUuid(cs.getBytes(columnIndex));
  }

  private static UUID bytesToUuid(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes == null) {
      return null;
    }
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    Long high = byteBuffer.getLong();
    Long low = byteBuffer.getLong();
    return new UUID(high, low);
  }
}
```

To register the type handler globally...

- if you are using `mybatis-spring-boot`, specify `mybatis.type-handlers-package` in your `application.properties`.
- if you are not using spring-boot, set `typeHandlersPackage` or `typeHandlers` property of `SqlSessionFactoryBean`.

If, for some reason, you cannot register the type handler globally, you may have to pass the fully-qualified-name of the type handler when initializing the `SqlColumn<UUID> myUuidColumn`.

Comment: Yes with Spring boot mybatis starter.. This works fine.